# Replacing a certain string after a certain character in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, find-and-replace

I'm organizing my Mame files in a way that all the games marked with *mature* (meaning adult content) are filtered out. I have a text file in Excel (one game per line) and I'd like to accomplish the following:

Original line: `4psimasy=Tabletop / Mahjong *Mature*`

Target line: `4psimasy=Mature`

How could I do this?

Comment: So in each cell that contains the word "Mature", you want to remove everything between the `=` sign and that word?

Comment: Yes, that's it :)

Comment: The split function and an if on the array within a macro is what you want!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your game is in `A1`, something like this should do the trick:

```
=IFERROR(REPLACE(A1; SEARCH("="; A1) + 1; SEARCH("Mature"; A1) - SEARCH("="; A1) - 1; ""); A1)
```

(Note: depending on your regional settings, you may have to replace the semicolons in the formula with commas.)

[image]

The `REPLACE()` function removes (by replacing with an empty string `""`) a given number of characters in the original string (`A1`) from the given starting position (right after the `=` sign).

If `A1` doesn't contain the word "Mature" (or the `=` sign, for that matter), Excel throws the `#VALUE` error, which the `IFERROR()` function catches and returns the contents of `A1` instead.

---

After the above, you can hide and lock the column with the original names, or copy the censored names and choose "Paste Special..." → Values to completely replace the original names. Or if your desired output is a text file, you can also move the censored names to a separate worksheet and export only that from Excel.

Comment: If it helps clarify the solution, I can write up a detailed explanation of the formula, like I did [here](http://superuser.com/a/478917/108226).

Comment: Thanks Indrek :) I'll test this as soon as I get to my other computer that has Excel. I'll report how it goes.

Comment: Works like a charm :) Thank you so much Indrek!

Comment: @user161284 You're welcome. Please feel free to mark my answer as accepted by clicking the green checkmark outline below it.